# $I = \int_0^k z^{m_1 - 1} \ln(1 + z) \left(\frac{m_1 z}{a} + \frac{m_2}{b} \right)^{-(m_1 + m_2)} \mathrm dz.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

**Question:** How to find the closed-form solution for the given integral?
$$I = \int_0^k z^{m_1 - 1} \ln(1 + z) \left(\dfrac{m_1 z}{a} + \dfrac{m_2}{b} \right)^{-(m_1 + m_2)} \mathrm dz,$$
where $k, a, b, m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb R_+$. Any leads appreciated.

**Attempt**: I find it difficult because of the limits. In case the upper limit is $\infty$, the integral can be solved as 
\begin{align}
I < & \int_0^\infty z^{m_1 - 1} \ln(1 + z) \left(\dfrac{m_1 z}{a} + \dfrac{m_2}{b} \right)^{-(m_1 + m_2)} \mathrm dz \\
= & \left( \dfrac{b}{m_2}\right)^{m_1 + m_2}\int_0^\infty z^{m_{1} - 1} G_{2, 2}^{1, 2} \left( z  \left\vert \begin{smallmatrix} 1, & 1 \\[0.6em] 1, & 0\end{smallmatrix} \right.\right) G_{1, 1}^{1, 1} \left( \left. \dfrac{b m_1}{a m_2} z\right\vert \begin{smallmatrix} 1 - m_{1} - m_{2}\\[0.6em] 0\end{smallmatrix}\right) \mathrm dz \\
= & \left( \dfrac{b}{m_2}\right)^{m_1 + m_2} G_{3, 3}^{3, 2} \left( \left. \dfrac{b m_1}{a m_2} \right\vert \begin{smallmatrix} 1- m_{1} - m_{2}, & -m_{1}, & 1 - m_{1} \\[0.6em] 0, & -m_{1}, & -m_{1}\end{smallmatrix}\right),
\end{align}
where the integration above is solved using [[1](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=96930), eqns. (7, 10, 11, & 21)] and $G_{p, q}^{m, n}(\cdot)$ is Meijer's G-function. But this results in a (very) loose bound.

Comment: This is a very interesting question! I hope it gets a lot of attention.

Comment: You cannot say "the integral is solved" when you have a mere upper bound...

Comment: @JeanMarie: By "the integral is solved", I meant the integral in the upper bound!

Comment: I think you can see what is going on by looking at the upper bound. This is a Meijer's G-function of two variables, which may be expressed by the more general H-Fox-function of two variables or the Kampe Ferriet function, with the more familiar Appell-functions.

Comment: Have you attempted to expand $\log(1+z)$ and integrate term by term ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Here the variable $z$ may take a value greater than 1, so I am not sure about the expansion for $\log(1 + z)$.

Comment: You can assume in this case that $k<1$ in order to be in the domain of convergence of the classical expansion of $\log(1+z)$ and (maybe) for $k>1$ make a change of variable $Z=1/z$ and work with the expansion of $\log(1+1/Z)$...

Comment: @Nash J. Your integral can be simplify reduced to $\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Beta}\left[c_1 z,\alpha ,\beta \right]}{1+c_2 \
z} \, dz$. In a project, which is releated to the electrochemical reactions of a cell I was confronted with that integral and solved it after a very long time. I expressed the solution in form of a finite sum of Appel-Functions, a special case of Kampe Ferriet  function. The derivation is so long, that posting is almost impossible. If you are interessed I can share the notebook with you!

Comment: @stocha I'll be very much thankful to you if you can please share the same with me!

Comment: I found the solution of the integral in the paper Sanchis-Lozano. I is formula (4) or Expression 2.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following simplifications: First we introduce the abbreviations:
$$\delta =k^{m_1} \left(\frac{m_2}{b}\right){}^{-\left(m_1+m_2\right)}$$
$$\nu =-\frac{b k m_1}{a m_2}$$
$$\mu =m_1+m_2$$
to write:
$$I=\delta  \int_0^1 z^{-1+m_1} \text{Log}[1+k z] (1-\nu  z)^{-\mu } \
\, dz$$ Second we have to do a partial integration with:

$$\nu ^{-m_1} \partial _z\left(\text{Beta}\left[\nu  z,m_1,1-\mu \right] \text{Log}[1+kz]\right)=\frac{k \nu ^{-m_1} \text{Beta}\left[z \nu ,m_1,1-\mu
\right]}{1+k z}+z^{-1+m_1} (1-z \nu )^{-\mu } \text{Log}[1+k z]$$
to reduce the integral to:
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Beta}[z \nu ,m_1,1-\mu ]}{1+k z} \, dz$$
Now we see that the solution of the integral is a function of two variables. This integral appears in a more general form in the calculation of the porosity of an electrode of a lead acid battery. The solution is needed to calculate the coverage with lead sulfate and have information of the state of charge of the battery. If $k=\nu$ the solution is given by [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/21/01/02/02/). For the general the strategy is to express the numerator and denominator as a hypergeometric function:
$$\text{Beta}[z \nu ,\alpha ,1-\mu ]=\frac{(z \nu )^{m_1} \text{HypergeometricPFQ}\left[\left\{m_1,\mu \right\},\left\{m_1+1\right\},z \nu \right]}{m_1}$$

$$\frac{1}{1+k z}=\text{Hypergeometric2F1}[1,1,1,-z k]$$

As a result one has to solve the integral over two hypergeometric functions. This is done by [SRIVASTAVA](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01112721) and leads to a Kampe de Feriet Function. The generalization is a H-Fox-Function with two variables. If I have a email address I can share the notebook with you and also the paper.

EDIT

I found the solution of the integral in the paper [Sanchis-Lozano](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271610/1-s2.0-S0377042700X00489/1-s2.0-S0377042797001386/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEOT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDyc6FilMRj5nLuQe1Ka1B95RVtCbhUzql6Bg544vUHpQIhAODFF3jjMU9LSmAw8aJ%2F66twl%2F8TL4Tg2gTxiPouzLbGKuMDCKz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgyM%2FlOhUOQ4qUUExboqtwNOGnercsQtY26GEVrfnJHNINy5LIZURMCv6v2oCMC84KQPrevAGFVj9ylKYg9hrwc2snlUf8LenjxCvbAqSUErNz3ein%2Bga1%2BpDAGBGD0y%2BJV%2BQcISauXPVRXmxN60VuHENFfVNbP8FjwbQt3VkcxAkE3tucAr2wA0j%2BxJ%2B4wOnenLHNSsbK1bIJHZeopZ%2Brq78yAnRJ4ZFn%2FBIMF%2BqLouYgacp1yfR9Y%2BbncBLxYH3vYdIE2JHJ9dHBrOYwiRnZXTM733PjWgB2C1DU2vQlmxhjn0HwF64idr%2BHIp3KKWJ%2FFMDtbgxtuK8kY%2BHsUSBZsPIwdHtL9IsnatFOo7sQK8963R1TTqcf7pvx4RwsRXj37y01pIyvRVpgkd7hccPj62SKKALPFobXMFqE4J%2F8NAd8dS8wEYN5Va7p4%2BmVkNy5Tv9lWJwM%2FIV%2B6faX5%2F0Pfv3fo0xlow3205FBOTX1cH%2FI33hk2ehsQj2OnaFB%2FnM%2Bh8XZQ8wlxTK7E8owt5qJkY3HuKJI6sNo%2FGsidEk5mMO0sN1qvXEeLMbzkT%2BA31aklgRkBkPC7mzfdN%2B0xzZVm3kL0MVqWdMOfGw%2BUFOrMBm%2FvUfLUEyUfwZSAKqXgGX2vD6bhICVjQU1YHdR9hZZJG4RnE39e6NOmJ5t5G1ib%2BkfWMfoqskc72C4ShD5yUuVbsShgvSWoOhc5lqmWA8W3jf7j55LZMbHTwFLgy%2F8HjVO4EXvYmn5wVfSLrJfWDVV3T%2Bs8Lq1fQUwhoV77XcDqgNjZQr3wSBqVxRPbH2MFU6DRi8LGUf1cFMe6jY1tZwuYTnp1XQgC0jo1mdF9FUORyX6k%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3L3FUCXO&Expires=1555100697&Signature=CFwT9zPUTs68KaU%2BAQ2PIYtEByc%3D&hash=1a163ca90b0900a250fd90d3d592fe0545aecc86a10dcd0c0279ae04d5a935d9&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0377042797001386&tid=spdf-23be0092-332d-4749-a0ee-7d6d2eb3a525&sid=b91c25065a2dc04461693e30466e1f3d1041gxrqb&type=client). It is formula (4) or Expression 2.